# HiDPI scaling for Applications

Tags: gnome, scaling, 4k-monitor

I'm running Gnome Shell on Ubuntu using a 3440 x 1440 screen. Most of the time there is no issue with scaling but for some applications like Albert the scaling is wrong. In this screenshot everything looks normal.
[image]

But when I open the settings the scaling is off. For instance the text is to big.
[image]

How can I fix these issues?

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu Gnome and that solved the issue